# Error: Distribution for origin "xxx_domain_name" is disabled

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have integrated the AWS cloud front CDN in my wordpress site with help of W3 Total cache plugin. few days back it is working fine but now days it is showing

```
Error: Distribution for origin "XXXXXXDomain Name" is disabled.
```

I have tried with delete and create more than 3 times new distribution but issue are same still occurring.

Any once could you please help me.